# How to order node positions in this graph?

Tags: graphviz

I have the following Graph [Link](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1463127138373#digraph%20G%20%7B%0Adir%3D%22back%22%3B%0Af00%20-%3E%20f10%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af00%20-%3E%20f11%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f20%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f22%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f21%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af10%20-%3E%20f22%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f21%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af11%20-%3E%20f23%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0A%0A%0Af20%20-%3E%20f30%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af20%20-%3E%20f31%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af20%20-%3E%20f32%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af21%20-%3E%20f31%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af21%20-%3E%20f32%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af21%20-%3E%20f33%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af22%20-%3E%20f32%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af22%20-%3E%20f33%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af22%20-%3E%20f34%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af23%20-%3E%20f33%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af23%20-%3E%20f34%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af23%20-%3E%20f35%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0A%0A%0Af30%20-%3E%20f40%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af30%20-%3E%20f41%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af30%20-%3E%20f42%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af31%20-%3E%20f41%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af31%20-%3E%20f42%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af31%20-%3E%20f43%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af32%20-%3E%20f42%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af32%20-%3E%20f43%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af32%20-%3E%20f44%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af33%20-%3E%20f43%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af33%20-%3E%20f44%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af33%20-%3E%20f45%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af34%20-%3E%20f44%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af34%20-%3E%20f45%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af34%20-%3E%20f46%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af35%20-%3E%20f45%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af35%20-%3E%20f46%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af35%20-%3E%20f47%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af36%20-%3E%20f46%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af36%20-%3E%20f47%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af36%20-%3E%20f48%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0A%0A%0A%0Af40%20-%3E%20f50%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af40%20-%3E%20f51%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af40%20-%3E%20f52%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af41%20-%3E%20f51%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af41%20-%3E%20f52%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af41%20-%3E%20f53%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af42%20-%3E%20f52%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af42%20-%3E%20f53%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af42%20-%3E%20f54%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af43%20-%3E%20f53%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af43%20-%3E%20f54%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af43%20-%3E%20f55%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af44%20-%3E%20f54%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af44%20-%3E%20f55%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af44%20-%3E%20f56%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af45%20-%3E%20f55%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af45%20-%3E%20f56%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af45%20-%3E%20f57%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af46%20-%3E%20f56%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af46%20-%3E%20f57%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af46%20-%3E%20f58%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af47%20-%3E%20f57%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af47%20-%3E%20f58%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af47%20-%3E%20f59%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af48%20-%3E%20f58%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af48%20-%3E%20f59%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af48%20-%3E%20f510%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0Af49%20-%3E%20f59%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%3B%0Af49%20-%3E%20f510%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af49%20-%3E%20f511%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%0Af410%20-%3E%20f510%5Bdir%3D%22back%22%5D%3B%0Af410%20-%3E%20f511%5Bstyle%3Dinvis%5D%3B%0Af410%20-%3E%20f512%5Bdir%3Dback%2C%20constraint%3Dfalse%5D%0A%0A%0A%7D)

The Last row has trouble getting aligned. I have tried adding dummy nodes but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can constrain explicitly nodes to the same rank using `rank=same`:

```
digraph G {
dir="back";
{
  rank=same;
  edge[style=invis];
  f30->f31->f32->f33->f34->f35->f36;
}
{
  rank=same;
  edge[style=invis];
  f40->f41->f42->f43->f44->f45->f46->f47->f48->f49->f410;
}

{
  rank=same;
  edge[style=invis];
  f50->f51->f52->f53->f54->f55->f56->f57->f58->f59->f510->f511->f512;
}

f00 -> f10[dir="back"];
f00 -> f11[dir="back"];
f10 -> f20[dir="back"];
f11 -> f22[style=invis];
f10 -> f21[style=invis];
f10 -> f22[dir="back", constraint=false];
f11 -> f21[dir="back", constraint=false];
f11 -> f23[dir="back"];


f20 -> f30[dir="back"];
f20 -> f31[style=invis];
f20 -> f32[dir=back, constraint=false]
f21 -> f31[dir=back, constraint=false];
f21 -> f32[style=invis];
f21 -> f33[dir="back"]
f22 -> f32[dir="back"];
f22 -> f33[style=invis];
f22 -> f34[dir=back, constraint=false]
f23 -> f33[dir=back, constraint=false];
f23 -> f34[style=invis];
f23 -> f35[dir="back"];


f30 -> f40[dir="back"];
f30 -> f41[style=invis];
f30 -> f42[dir=back, constraint=false]
f31 -> f41[dir=back, constraint=false];
f31 -> f42[style=invis];
f31 -> f43[dir="back"]
f32 -> f42[dir="back"];
f32 -> f43[style=invis];
f32 -> f44[dir=back, constraint=false]
f33 -> f43[dir=back, constraint=false];
f33 -> f44[style=invis];
f33 -> f45[dir="back"]
f34 -> f44[dir="back"];
f34 -> f45[style=invis];
f34 -> f46[dir=back, constraint=false]
f35 -> f45[dir=back, constraint=false];
f35 -> f46[style=invis];
f35 -> f47[dir="back"]
f36 -> f46[dir="back"];
f36 -> f47[style=invis];
f36 -> f48[dir=back, constraint=false];



f40 -> f50[dir="back"];
f40 -> f51[style=invis];
f40 -> f52[dir=back, constraint=false]
f41 -> f51[dir=back, constraint=false];
f41 -> f52[style=invis];
f41 -> f53[dir="back"]
f42 -> f52[dir="back"];
f42 -> f53[style=invis];
f42 -> f54[dir=back, constraint=false]
f43 -> f53[dir=back, constraint=false];
f43 -> f54[style=invis];
f43 -> f55[dir="back"]
f44 -> f54[dir="back"];
f44 -> f55[style=invis];
f44 -> f56[dir=back, constraint=false]
f45 -> f55[dir=back, constraint=false];
f45 -> f56[style=invis];
f45 -> f57[dir="back"]
f46 -> f56[dir="back"];
f46 -> f57[style=invis];
f46 -> f58[dir=back, constraint=false]
f47 -> f57[dir=back, constraint=false];
f47 -> f58[style=invis];
f47 -> f59[dir="back"]
f48 -> f58[dir="back"];
f48 -> f59[style=invis];
f48 -> f510[dir=back, constraint=false]
f49 -> f59[dir=back, constraint=false];
f49 -> f510[style=invis];
f49 -> f511[dir="back"]
f410 -> f510[dir="back"];
f410 -> f511[style=invis];
f410 -> f512[dir=back, constraint=false]
}
```